# Pulling excel rows to display as a grid in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am imaging fluorescent cells from a 384-well plate and my software spits out a formatted excel analysis of the data (16 rowsx24 columns of images turns into a list of data, with 2 measurements from each well, ~800 data points). Because there is a lot of manual interaction with the data, I want to automate my work by taking the information that's indexed in the excel sheet and map it as a tkinter grid. I want to take my data, have it formatted from a list back to the original 16x24 display. I want to be able to interact with that data, among other things, but as a newbie in python, I'm having a difficult time mapping this data.

I  used pandas to read my dataframe, but can't seem to display my list to the appropriate grid box. Ideally, I'd like the values in the excel list to display on the corresponding cell in the tkinter grid. For example, in my excel list, [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Zrm.jpg, the two data points from each well are listed. I want to take the values from each cell and display them to the corresponding grid in tkinter, so the average of values of "A1" would be mapped onto column 1, row 1 of the grid, A2 would be col 2 row 1, A3 would be col 3 row 1, and so on and so forth.

Any help would be great, thank you.

```
from tkinter import *

import pandas as pd

from pandas import ExcelWriter

from pandas import ExcelFile
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/Zammam/PycharmProjects/Filipin_Analysis_Zammam/data.xlsx', sheet_name='Dataps')
print(()
class Cell():
    FILLED_COLOR_BG = "green"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BG = "white"
    FILLED_COLOR_BORDER = "green"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER = "black"

    def __init__(self, master, x, y, size):
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size= size
        self.fill= False

    def _switch(self):
        """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
        self.fill= not self.fill

    def draw(self):

        if self.master != None :
            fill = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BG
            outline = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BORDER

            if not self.fill:
                fill = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BG
                outline = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill = fill, outline = outline)

class CellGrid(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master, rowNumber, columnNumber, cellSize, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width = cellSize * columnNumber , height = cellSize * rowNumber, *args, **kwargs)

        self.cellSize = cellSize

        self.grid = []
        for row in range(rowNumber):

            line = []
            for column in range(columnNumber):
                line.append(Cell(self, column, row, cellSize))

            self.grid.append(line)

        #memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
        self.switched = []

        #bind click action
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.handleMouseClick)  
        #bind moving while clicking
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.handleMouseMotion)
        #bind release button action - clear the memory of midified cells.
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.switched.clear())

        self.draw()



    def draw(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def create_text(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                for i in df:
                    cell.create_text(text = df)



    def _eventCoords(self, event):
        row = int(event.y / self.cellSize)
        column = int(event.x / self.cellSize)
        return row, column

    def handleMouseClick(self, event):
        row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
        cell = self.grid[row][column]
        cell._switch()
        cell.draw()
        #add the cell to the list of cell switched during the click
        self.switched.append(cell)

    def handleMouseMotion(self, event):
        row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
        cell = self.grid[row][column]

        if cell not in self.switched:
            cell._switch()
            cell.draw()
            self.switched.append(cell)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = Tk()

    grid = CellGrid(app, 16, 24, 15)
    grid.pack()

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its better if you remove the parts you interact with the labels, and just show the code where you try to extract excel datas and grid them and where you get the error from. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to figure precisely that -- how would I go about grabbing this excel data and display the each cell's value onto the tkinter grid. I currently don't have any idea how to go about that.
def create_text(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                for i in df:
                    cell.create_text(text = df)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pandas so I will use `openpyxl` to demonstrate. It will probably be something similar with pandas or even simpler.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

file = "your_excel_file.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
ws = wb.active

r = 0
for row in ws:
    c = 0
    for cell in row:
        tk.Label(root,text=cell.value).grid(row=r,column=c)
        c+=1
    r+=1

root.mainloop()
```

A quick look at using pandas instead:

```
df = pd.read_excel('your_excel_file.xlsx',header=None)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    c = 0
    for cell in row:
        tk.Label(root, text=cell).grid(row=i, column=c)
        c += 1
```