# Tkinter - Importing a small table to show in my gui box

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGliv.png)I would like the contents of the excel file to show up in the GUI box with out shrinking or eliminating columns or rows. THis code, truncates the columns and squeezes everything together.

```
import pandas as pd
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import tktable
    import os

root = Tk()
root.title('Import Instrument Sequence')
root.geometry('800x400')
#root.resizable(height = 10, width = 50)

#Creating a label
label = Label(root, text='Select Sequence File:')

#putting it on the screen
label.pack()

def browse():
    # Allow user to select a directory, file, and load the seq file
    sequence_filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename('/')
    sequence_file = pd.read_excel(sequence_filepath, header=0, index_col=0)
    work_directory = os.path.dirname(sequence_filepath)
    seq_text = Label(root, text=sequence_file).pack()
    print(sequence_file.head())
    
browse_button = Button(root, text='Browse & Load Sequence', padx=100, command=browse)
browse_button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It probably depends on your input data. Can you post an example (picture) of what is happening?

Comment: Thank you Ronald. I added a pic of what shows up. Hope you can see it. I've very new to all this. :)

Comment: There are 5 columns, 42 rows

Comment: Have you tried using a different method instead of `pack()`. Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912697/pulling-excel-rows-to-display-as-a-grid-in-tkinter

Comment: There is a pandas implementation of using the `grid()` packing method at the bottom of the answer

Comment: I searched about what options there are to manipulate printing a panda frame. I suppose you get the most control, indeed, by accessing each data cell or data column separately and placing it in several labels on the canvas.

Comment: I did try the grid() with different sizes (row, column, etc.) but it still is truncated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to experiment with. I got some results by manipulating the data with the `.to_string` method. (See [pandas.DataFrame.to_string](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)). This gave some good results after playing with different values:

```
seq_text = Label(root, text=sequence_file.to_string(col_space=30))
```

You can further experiment with justifying the text within a column, info for that is within the same link.

Comment: Ronald, this one looks alot better. Not exactly what I want it to look like, but definitely an excellent step! Thank you very much.